CVE - questions about status
Can someone explain what exacly mean status in specific linux versions ?

I have ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so thats mean that i must wait for fix that ?

First, it is a busybox version and not linux. Second, yes, do wait.

"Needed" means that that version is affected and does not yet have a fix. So yes, it means we need to wait.

"DNE" does not exist
"ignored" support has ended for one reason or another/ end-of-life.
"needs triage" work is needed to determine if the reported problem exists.
"not affected" vulnerability exists, but triage determined that the issue will not occur.
"needed" triage has determined that the package within the lineage is affected, but work to apply a fix is still needed.
"pending" a fix is made and a release of that fix is coming.
"released" fix been released

